# canvas after arc stroke line popping out

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working with Canvas and when I draw stoke like around an arc I am seeing with stroke line coming out:

Render circle function:

```
function renderCircle(radius, angle, circleLength, circleAngle, circleColor, circleBorderColor, circleTextColor, circleFontStyle, value) {
var text = "$" + (typeof value === "number" ? value : this.data.value);
        var coord = this.getCoordOnCircle(radius * 1.21, angle);
        var circlePoint = {
            x: this.gaugeCenterX - coord.x,
            y: this.gaugeCenterY - coord.y
        };
        var ctx = this.ctx;
        ctx.fillStyle = circleColor;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(circlePoint.x, circlePoint.y);
        coord = this.getCoordOnCircle(circleLength * 1.18, angle - circleAngle);
        ctx.arc((circlePoint.x + coord.x), (circlePoint.y + coord.y), circleLength, 0, 25 * Math.PI);
        ctx.strokeStyle = circleBorderColor;
        if(this.isAnimationEnabled) {
         ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        }

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillStyle = circleTextColor;
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.font = circleFontStyle;
        ctx.fillText(text, (circlePoint.x + coord.x), (circlePoint.y + coord.y) + 5);
}
```

[image]

you can see here the blue line is slightly coming out. does any one know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Firgured it out,
I was stupid to add  ctx.moveTo(circlePoint.x, circlePoint.y);

I removed it and it fixed